# New Line JavaScript with label

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Location Test </title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> Location </h1>
      <label id = "Address"> </label>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Log Out" id="LogOut">
  <script>
    const logoutButton = document.getElementById("LogOut");

function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(Position) {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
                (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
                currentdate.getFullYear() + ". " +
                currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
                currentdate.getMinutes() + "." +
                currentdate.getSeconds() + ". ";
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "Latitude: " + Position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Longitude: " + Position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Accuracy: " + Position.coords.accuracy;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Heading towards direction: " + Position.coords.heading;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Speed: " + Position.coords.speed;
            var api_key = '206170168bcf4fdf905d85a34f7b3d79';
            var latitude = Position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = Position.coords.longitude;
            var api_url = 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json'
            var request_url = api_url +
                '?' +
                'key=' + api_key +
                '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(latitude + ',' + longitude) +
                '&pretty=1' +
                '&no_annotations=1';
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', request_url, true);
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    // Success!
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "  Address: " + data.results[0].formatted; // print the location
                } else if (request.status <= 500) {
                    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                    console.log("unable to geocode! Response code: " + request.status);
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    console.log('error msg: ' + data.status.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("server error");
                }
            };
            request.onerror = function() {
                console.log("unable to connect to server");
            };
            request.send(); // make the request
        },
        function(PositionError) {
            document.getElementById("Latitude").innerHTML = "Could not get latitude";
            document.getElementById("Longitude").innerHTML = "Could not get longitude";
        })
}
getLocation();
setInterval(getLocation, 1000 * 5)
logoutButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        getLocation();
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }) 
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

That code is supposed to display the user's coordinates, direction, address, etc. Then after every 5 minutes, it repeats it. When they log off, it does it one last time. I have a single label to display the addresses. So let's say it's

```
Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want it to constantly print this:

```
Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Instead I get

```
Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx Last Sync: 5/12/2021. 14:13.28. Latitude: xxx Longitude: -xxx Accuracy: 13.454 Heading towards direction: null Speed: null Address: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The simplest but not a canonical answer would be add <br> to the end of the line

Comment: `\n` has no effect in an `innerHTML`. And `.textContent` will strip the HTML out.

Comment: Where do I add <br>? I've tried

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer `document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "  Address: " + data.results[0].formatted + "<br>"; // print the location`

Comment: Did not work though

Comment: Also change `document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "Last Sync: "` to `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Ah, I've understood the question that a new line should be in the code, not in the output. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to to call *document.getElementById("Address").textContent* every time you want to append some text to the content of *Address* element. You can easily use *element.innerHTML+= 'some new content'* and at the end of every iteration append a *br* tag to make a new line. Below code should work for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Location Test </title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> Location </h1>
      <label id = "Address"> </label>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Log Out" id="LogOut">
  <script>
    const logoutButton = document.getElementById("LogOut");

function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(Position) {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
                (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
                currentdate.getFullYear() + ". " +
                currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
                currentdate.getMinutes() + "." +
                currentdate.getSeconds() + ". ";
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += "Latitude: " + Position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += " Longitude: " + Position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += " Accuracy: " + Position.coords.accuracy;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += " Heading towards direction: " + Position.coords.heading;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += " Speed: " + Position.coords.speed;
            var api_key = '206170168bcf4fdf905d85a34f7b3d79';
            var latitude = Position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = Position.coords.longitude;
            var api_url = 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json'
            var request_url = api_url +
                '?' +
                'key=' + api_key +
                '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(latitude + ',' + longitude) +
                '&pretty=1' +
                '&no_annotations=1';
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', request_url, true);
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    // Success!
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML += "  Address: " + data.results[0].formatted; // print the location
                    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML+= "<br/>"; 
                } else if (request.status <= 500) {
                    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                    console.log("unable to geocode! Response code: " + request.status);
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    console.log('error msg: ' + data.status.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("server error");
                }
            };
            request.onerror = function() {
                console.log("unable to connect to server");
            };
            request.send(); // make the request
        },
        function(PositionError) {
            document.getElementById("Latitude").innerHTML = "Could not get latitude";
            document.getElementById("Longitude").innerHTML = "Could not get longitude";
        })
}
getLocation();
setInterval(getLocation, 1000)
logoutButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        getLocation();
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }) 
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```